# How to use Django admin interface to show uploaded files decently?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, image-uploading

I'm bulding my new Django app. It's in the very beginning stages. So right now I'm just concentrating on the designing the data models. Forms, views, templates, front-end-AJAX etc will all come later. I'm using the Django Admin interface to create and view dummy model objects.

I have a model with an ImageField attribute. Using the admin interface, I'm able upload a file called taco.jpg to this model. I can go into the file system and see that this file has been successfully uploaded. It's file path also shows up in the admin interface:

[image]

However, when I click that link, it produces an error because there is no route specified to that file in urls.py:

[image]

**How do I make it so that whenever I upload a file, route to it is automatically added in urls.py? 
And how do I make it so that a thumbnail of the photo appears in the drilldown view in the admin interface (and if I click on that thumbnail, the full size image should display)**

Here is my urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Here is my data model:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')
```

And here is Admin file:

```
class PhotoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ["image",]
    list_display = ("image",)
admin.site.register(Photo, PhotoAdmin)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you forgot to serve media files to do so just follow [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user)

To show a preview of the image in the **admin** you can do the following :

Add this to `PhotoAdmin`:

```
def image_img(self):
    if self.image:
        return u'<img src="%s" />' % self.image.url 
    else:
        return '(No image found)'
image_img.short_description = 'Thumb'
image_img.allow_tags = True
```

So `PhotoAdmin` should look this way:

```
class PhotoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ["image",]
    list_display = ("image","image_img")


  def image_img(self):
        if self.image:
            return u'<img src="%s" />' % self.image.url 
        else:
            return '(No image found)'
    image_img.short_description = 'Thumb'
    image_img.allow_tags = True
```

Comment: Thanks. Now the image file is being successfully served when I click on the link in the admin interface. Isn't there a way to have a thumbnail of the image show up right in the admin interface right next to the attribute field name? That's what I'm going for.